# Error "Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2" in CNN for mnist dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm designing a CNN for `mnist` dataset. Then it returns an error

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for '{{node conv2d_23/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](batch_normalization_19/cond/Identity, conv2d_23/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,2,2,12], [3,3,12,12].
```

I tried to change `padding = 'valid'` to `padding = 'same'`, but the problem persists. Could you please elaborate on this error and how to fix it?

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Input, Reshape, BatchNormalization
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam

X = Input(shape = (28, 28, 1))

for k in range(3):
    X = Conv2D(filters = 3 * (2 ** k), kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Conv2D(filters = 3 * (2 ** k), kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'valid')(X)            
    X = Dropout(0.25 + (0.1 * k))(X)

X = Flatten()(X)
Y = Dense(units = 512, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform')(X)
X = BatchNormalization()(X)
X = Dropout(0.5)(X)
Y = Dense(units = 10, activation = 'softmax')(X)

model = Model(X, Y)
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'Adam',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data() 
# Reshape dataset to match the expected dimensions of 2D Convolution
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)

y_train = to_categorical(y_train, n_classes)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, n_classes)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.0
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.0

history = model.fit(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 32),
                    epochs = 10,
                    validation_data = (x_test, y_test))

plt.plot(history.history['loss'], 'tab:blue',
         history.history['val_loss'], 'tab:orange')
plt.legend(['loss', 'val_loss'])
loss_path = os.path.join(OUTDIR, lossplot_filename)
plt.savefig(loss_path)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you also try to set `same` padding for CNNs? Also might not be related to the problem but your loss function is not correct as you are doing multi-class classification.

Comment: @Frightera I change `padding = 'same'` and `loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'`, but the problem persists.

Comment: @gobrewers14 I tried to add `input_shape=(28,28,1), data_format='channels_last'`, but the problem persists.

Comment: You use max pooling with strides of 2, three times. After the first time, tensor shape is `28//4` so 7, after three times it's reduced to less than zero

Comment: Thank you @NicolasGervais. I change the strides to 1 and it works :))